# How can I break nomencl subgroups into pages?

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I'm using `nomencl` to create a acronyms list and a symbols list. I'm using the code below:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
  \pdfbookmark[0]{\nomname}{las}
  \makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Acronyms}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{S}{Symbols}{%
]}
```

And to generate the list:

```
\nomenclature[A]{CC}{Creative Commons}
\nomenclature[S]{N}{Newton (unit measure)}
\printnomenclature[2cm]
```

But they are rendered in the same page. How can I break each group in its own page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine your `\nomgroup` using `\ifthenelse` (inspired from the [package documentation](http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/nomencl.pdf)) instead of `\ifstrequal`, and insert a `\clearpage` command before the start of `Symbols`. You can obviously generalize this to any number of subgroups that you create using this method.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature

 \RequirePackage{ifthen}
 \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}{%
         \clearpage\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Symbols}]}{}}}

\begin{document}
    \nomenclature[A]{CC}{Creative Commons}
    \nomenclature[S]{N}{Newton (unit measure)}
    \printnomenclature[2cm]
\end{document}
```

First page:

[image: first]

Second page:

[image]